# DNN C# module dev - nullable value

Tags: c#, nullable

I develop a dnn module and use public class classNameInfo: IHydratable (c#)

Can someone explain **why this code always return 0 from the db**:

```
System.Nullable<int> _ProductID;
_ProductID = (oReader["ProductID"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)oReader["ProductID"]);
```

**while this code returns the correct value?**

```
int? y = (oReader["ProductID"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : (int?)oReader["ProductID"]);
if (y != null)
{
_ProductID = (int)oReader["ProductID"];
}
else
{
_ProductID = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to convert `anything` to `int?`, it will only work if the type of said `anything` is *exactly* int. Every other direct conversion will fail. Since the database types are never "exactly `int`", that conversion can't work.

To make the code shorter, you can use the following statement:

```
_ProductID = oReader["ProductID"] == System.DBNull.Value ? new int?() : (int)oReader["ProductID"];
```

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. So, do you approve the approach I took here (except for the code writing method)? Thank you for the short code :)